# Artifactory Bitbucket mainframe Integration

Tags: bitbucket, artifactory, mainframe

We are planning to use artifactory for mainframe COBOL.

We are also planning to use bitbucket as SCM tool for mainframe COBOL.

Can you please guide us on how to go about?

Thanks,
Shnkr

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bit bucket (or any GIT based system), you will need to be able to compile and move compiled objects to target datasets. IBM has a new product called Dependency Based Build, which is designed to integrate with GIT and other open SCM systems. It is Groovy based, and can call the COBOL, PL/I and Assembler compilers. It integrates with IBM Developer for System z (which is IBM's eclipse based IDE for mainframe development). This tool also allows you to debug, unit test, and analyze code coverage of your source. 
Here's a demo of DBB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsZDlKIDRXI

Also, using these for your toolchain, you will be able to store your compiled objects (load modules, listings, DBRM, etc) into Artifactory, but deployment can be a bear if you are just using open source tools. I would personally recommend Ubancode Deploy for z/OS deployment as it can handle complex deployment scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

For B.B. it totally depends on your IDE. Look at IBM’s eclipse bases stuff.

I have no idea how or if your can reasonably store mainframe COBOL artifacts in Artifactory - have you looked at their docs?

Answer (score 0):

JFrog Artifactory does not come with an out of the box support for COBOL binary packages.
You can take a look at [Generic repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-GenericRepositories), which allows storing any type of binary, as a possible solution. Using generic repositories will allow you to benefit from setting [permissions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions), defining [layouts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) and other Artifactory capabilities.